# How do I add a new property to $scope from a directive in Angular when inside of ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive inside of ng-repeat. This directive generates a uniquely named property and sets it to an object that was retrieved as JSON from the server. I will have multiple ng-repeat sections on a given page with my custom directive inside of it.

In my main controller for this page, I need to respond to events from these directives and update other elements on the page. I don't have full control of the events (they are 3rd party controls) so I can't really modify their parameters or anything. The properties created by this directive contains information I need from within my controller in order to make decisions about how to respond to them.

When I fire an event on the main controller, I don't see these new properties on $scope. If I move the elements out of the ng-repeat I do see them. I am not using a hidden scope for my directive.

Here's a simple version of what I'm doing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);


    app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.list = [];
      $scope.list.push({ sample: "item" });
      console.log('controller called');
      $scope.doSomething = function() {
        console.log('doSomething called');
        console.log($scope["myVariable"]);
        $scope.list = [];
        $scope.list.push({ sample: "item" });
      };
    }]);

    app.directive('testDirective', ['$http', function ($http) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function (scope, element, attrib) {
          var setValue = function() {
            scope["myVariable"] = "TEST!" + Date();
            console.log('myVariable is set.'); 
          };

          setValue();
        }
      };
    }]);
  </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="TestApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
      <div >
        <div ng-repeat="item in list" >
          <a href="#" test-directive ng-click="doSomething()">Click</a>  
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here's the same code on [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VTgQPeRvjf8ZMpd88ppD?p=preview)

Can you help to to understand why this is happening?

I see two possible solutions from other questions here - one, I could create a controller that is shared by this directive. That's not really ideal since I need to be able to hook these directives up in different ways. Second, I see that I could probably use a service for sharing this data since it's a singleton, but that kind of bothers me - I'd really prefer it stay "local" to this controller/scope (but I may not have a choice about that).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't directly access parent scope items in a directive. The variable to be set or modified should be passed in.

```
scope: {
  'testDirective': '='
},
link: function (scope, element, attrib) {
  var setValue = function() {
    scope.testDirective = "TEST!" + Date();
    console.log('myVariable is set.'); 
  };

  setValue();
}
```

That property should always have a dot in it.

```
<a href="#" test-directive="data.myVariable" ng-click="doSomething()">Click</a>
```

That is now available on the controller as `data.myVariable`

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vwp22BUenZpohzSxtX63?p=preview)